# only get the h1 text no span text in python

Tags: python

I have a code like this i have tried to get the data in h1 .here it is 'The Wire'.But i am getting all the text in the h1.

```
<h1 id="aiv-content-title" class="js-hide-on-play"> 
The Wire
    <span class="num-of-seasons">5 Seasons</span>
    <span class="release-year">2002</span>
</h1>
```

The output i am getting is The `Wire5 Seasons2002`

```
heading=elm.find('h1',id='aiv-content-title')
print heading
seasons=elm.find('span',{'class':'num-of-seasons'})

if seasons=='None':
    print '1'
elif seasons!='None':
    print seasons.text

release_year=elm.find('span',{'class':'release-year'})
print release_year.text
print
```

When i have tried this code i am getting this way

`The Wire5 Seasons2002
5 Seasons
2002`

I am expecting something like this

`The Wire
5 Seasons
2002`

Comment: Everything is under the h1 tag, so I expect its getting all of the data from there as thats what you've asked for in the code, rather than just the small amount. (Just a thought)

Comment: @Maximas Is there any way i can get only `the Wire` as output without span text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
h1_element = elm.find('h1',{id:'aiv-content-title'})
num_seasons = h1_element.find('span',{'class':'num-of-seasons'}).getText().strip()
release_year = h1_element.find('span',{'class':'release-year'}).getText().strip()

while h1_element.find('span'):
   h1_element.find('span').extract() 
   # This will remove the span elements in the h1 element

print h1_element.getText().strip()
print num_seasons
print release_year
```

Answer (score -1):

I have come to solution,but seams a bit tricky

Here is the code ,Hope this will help some freshers into this field

```
elm=soup.find('div', id="dv-dp-main-content")
heading=elm.find('h1',id='aiv-content-title')
heading=heading.text
seasons=elm.find('span',{'class':'num-of-seasons'})
if seasons=='None':
    no_seasons='1 Season'
elif seasons!='None':
    no_seasons=seasons.text


release_year=elm.find('span',{'class':'release-year'})
releaseyr=release_year.text


rmstr=heading.replace(releaseyr," ")
name=rmstr.replace(no_seasons," ")
print name
print no_seasons
print releaseyr
```